# Symfony3 upload file without using FormBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have a project with files and when I create new project I have form created with `FormBuilder` and there I have a field from `FileType` and it is converted then to `UploadedFile` and it works fine. What I want is to be able to upload after that files without having to edit the project. A simple "Add more files" button. No other fields required and therefore - no need for `FormBuilder`. Also I don't want to have "save" button after "Add more files" is clicked. I want to click it choose my files and when I click "Open" the form to be submited. This I have achieved with the following code

```
<form action="{{ path('image_upload', { 'id': project.id }) }}" method="post" name="form">                              
  <div class="col-md-2" id="imageUpload">
    <span>Add More Files</span>
      <input type="file" readonly="readonly" id="imageUpload" name="image_upload[]" onchange="form.submit()" multiple/><div class="upload_icon"></div>
  </div>    
</form>
```

As you can see this form is only with this one button which `onChange` submits it. My problem is that after submission the files are not `UploadedFile` type and the Service I have for uploading images doesnot work. I tried creating an instance of `UploadedFile` on my own but it requires `filePath` which I have no idea how to take.

This is what is submitted 
[image]

From this I don't know how to take filePath to actually add it to the constructor of `UploadedFile`. Also when I debug what happens during creation of the project (where I use `FileType`) I see that the filePath is "C:\xampp\tmp" which I have no idea from where it comes. My first thought was to simply add it to the constructor of `UploadedFile` with this code

```
$file = new UploadedFile("C:\\xampp\\tmp",$file);
```

When I run it I receive this error -

> The file "C:\xampp\tmp" does not exist

So to recap - this is the path which $file->getPath() gives me when I use `FileType`, but without it when I have simple upload button, it doesnot exist.

At this point I surrendered and was like "Okay...If it wants me to use FormBuilder so badly - then I will". And here is the code in AddFileType (which is related to no entity or anything)

```
$builder->
        add("addFiles",FileType::class,array(
            'label'=>'Add More Files',
            'multiple'=> true,
            'mapped'=> false,
            "required"=>false
        ));
```

And here is the other problem - I want to be able to submit the form without submit button. Simply when I click "Add More Files" and select some files the form to be submited for me.

My question - Is there a way to get the filePath when using simple upload button and therefore create an instance of `UploadedFile` and send it to my database from my Service. If not - is there a way with `FormBuilder` to make it so when FileType button is clicked to submit the form without any submit button required.

Comment: You can use VichUploaderBundle. It's easy, simple and helpfull.

Documentation is here 
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set mapped to true, because by setting it to false it won't be a relation between this field and the database's field

```
$builder->
    add("addFiles",FileType::class,array(
        'label'=>'Add More Files',
        'multiple'=> true,
        'mapped'=> true,
        "required"=>false
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addArticleAction(Request $request){

    //get pic from http request
    $Image = $this->getRequest()->files->get('artPic'); 

    //generate a unique name for pic
    $picName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'-'.$Image->getClientOriginalName();

    //move pic to a directory
    $Image->move(
            $this->getParameter('pic_directory'),
            $picName
        );

    //store picName in db
    $article = new FlashInfo;
    $article->setPhoto($picName);

      //other data  
     $request = $request->request->all();
     $article->setTitle($request['arTitle']);
     $article->setTitle($request['arText']);
     $article->setTitle($request['artSource']);


 return new Response(json_encode(array('status'=>'success')));


}
```